# Order DataTable using LINQ based on a Class Collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class and I am creation its collection like this

```
class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    // ID will remain unique in collection

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
List<Foo> sc = new List<Foo>();

sc.Add(new Foo()
{
    ID = 0,
    Name= "Michael"
});

sc.Add(new Foo()
{
    ID = 2,
    Name= "Natasha"
});

sc.Add(new Foo()
{
    ID = 1,
    Name= "Casandra"
});
```

Then I get a DataTable

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTableMethod();
```

Datatable contains only name and not ID and will always have names less than collection. (bcoz collection is master collection)

Now I want to sort my datatable based on `"name"` but based on sorting of Foo Class collection which will be based on id.

Result after sorting datatable should be

```
Michael
Casandra
Natasha
```

I tried

```
var v = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(What should i write here?);
```

Comment: Just guessing here, but does `var v = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(row => row["Name"]);` work?

Comment: `var v = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(c => c["name"]);`?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Look at result in question. you answer will give Casandra, Michael, Natasha.

Comment: Woops, misread the question. You want the names sorted by their associated `ID`, correct? @NikhilAgrawal Yeah, _just_ noticed that. :)

Comment: @PLB: Look at result in question. you answer will give Casandra, Michael, Natasha.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal What columns have you defined/populated for your `DataTable` in `GetDataTableMethod()`?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal `Now I want to sort my datatable based on "name" but based on sorting of Foo Class collection` This is quite confusing. Probably you want to sort by `ID` and not by `name`, don't you?

Comment: Sorry @NikhilAgrawal, I missed your edit which really spells out the problem. Let me see if I got this correct: the `DataTable` provided to you does _not_ contain `Foo` objects. Rather it just gives you names. Programmatically, you build `Foo` objects, and you want to match/sort the `DataTable` based on the `Foo` objects joined by the matching `Name` property, correct?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you have collection which has data including ids and stored procedure that returns `DataTable` containing only one of its component. The simplest way is to iterate through list of data rows and match respective value from the full list and order after that:

```
 List<Foo> sc = new List<Foo>();

 sc.Add(new Foo()
 {
    ID = 0,
    Name = "Michael"
 });

 sc.Add(new Foo()
 {
    ID = 2,
    Name = "Natasha"
 });

 sc.Add(new Foo()
 {
    ID = 1,
    Name = "Casandra"
 });

 List<string> dt = new List<string>(); //For testing replaced just by string.

 dt.Add("Michael");

 dt.Add("Natasha");

 dt.Add("Casandra");

 var ordered = dt.Select(i => sc.First(c => c.Name == i)).OrderBy(i => i.ID);
```

[Demo (sorry for awful formatting).](http://ideone.com/z0Z2Hm)